# React <select> automatic change does not trigger onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect, react-usememo

In my page, I have two `<select>` elements, where the options of the second one depends on the value of the first one.

In this case, the "problem" is that the options for a certain value in the first select are different from the options given when the first select has another value. Basically:

- Alfa Romeo

  - Giulietta
  - Mito
- Porsche

  - Cayenne
  - 911

I've created a simple fiddle just to show you the example, and the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-autochange-7bfj6

Please, open the console to see what I'm talking about. So, basically, at start `'Porsche'` and `'911'` are selected. Then, if I change `'911'` to `'Cayenne'` everything is good.

The problem is when I change `'Porsche'` to `'Alfa'`: as it should be, the second select changes its value to `'Giulietta'`, BUT the `onChange` event of the second select is not triggered.
I'm mostly sure that the problem is some kind of de-synchronization between UI and state: in the state, the secondselect still has the value `'911'`, but since that option is no longer available in the second select, it autoselect the first possible value.. But that autoselection is just "graphical".

I know this could be fixed by adding a "null" value in the second select, with the option `<option value={''} label={'Select a Model'} />`. But I'd like to mantain the autoselection when the first select changes.

EDIT: actually, the fix I proposed is not an actual fix: that 'select a Model' options has the value `''`, but the `handleSelectSelectChange` is still not triggered, so, while the UI selected value is `''`, in the state I still have `'911'`

Answer (score 1):

```js
 React.useEffect(()=> {
    if (!secondOptionsMemoized.some(x=> x === secondSelectValue)) {
      console.log('Second Select Change in useEffect');
      setSecondSelectValue(secondOptionsMemoized[0]);
    }
 }, [secondSelectValue, secondOptionsMemoized]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this, and I'm sure it would work. Though, I was wondering if it exists a solution that maintain the synchronization between selected value and UI selected value. I mean, if tomorrow I'll have a similar case, I will need to write a similar useEffect to fix the issue.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-autochange-forked-e284j?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` instead of `useMemo` and another `state` which set the second options:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const alfaForSecondOptions = ["Giulietta", "Mito"];
  const otherForSecondOptions = ["Cayenne", "911"];

  const [firstSelectValue, setFirstSelectValue] = React.useState("Porsche");
  const [secondSelectValue, setSecondSelectValue] = React.useState("911");
  const [secondOptions, setSecondOptions] = React.useState(
    otherForSecondOptions
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(secondSelectValue);
  }, [secondOptions]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstSelectValue === "Alfa") {
      setSecondOptions(alfaForSecondOptions);
      setSecondSelectValue("Giulietta");
    } else {
      setSecondOptions(otherForSecondOptions);
      setSecondSelectValue("911");
    }
  }, [firstSelectValue]);

  const handleFirstSelectChange = (e) => {
    console.log("First Select Change", e.target.value);
    setFirstSelectValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSecondSelectChange = (e) => {
    console.log("Second Select Change", e.target.value);
    setSecondSelectValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        <p>Brand</p>
        <select onChange={handleFirstSelectChange} value={firstSelectValue}>
          <option value={"Alfa"} label={"Alfa"} />
          <option value={"Porsche"} label={"Porsche"} />
        </select>
      </label>

      <label>
        <p>Model</p>
        <select onChange={handleSecondSelectChange} value={secondSelectValue}>
          {secondOptions.map((x) => {
            return <option key={x} value={x} label={x} />;
          })}
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select Autochange (forked)]